# How to order Lucid Models results based on relation?

Tags: adonis.js, lucid

What I want is to order all `Service` model results based on a relation (that *belongsTo* the same `ServiceCategory`) like Laravel does, something like this:

```js
const services = await Service
  .query()
  .orderBy('categories.id', 'desc')
  .fetch()
```

The problem is that Lucid doesn't understand it and gives the following error:

> select * from `services` order
>   by `categories`.`id` asc - ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column
>   'categories.id' in 'order clause'

This is the Service model:

```js
const Model = use('Model')

class Service extends Model {
  categories() {
    return this
      .belongsToMany('App/Models/ServiceCategory')
      .withTimestamps()
  }
}

module.exports = Service
```

This is the ServiceCategory model:

```js
const Model = use('Model')

class ServiceCategory extends Model {
  services() {
    return this
      .belongsToMany('App/Models/Service')
      .withTimestamps()
  }
}

module.exports = ServiceCategory
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [with()](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_eager_loading)

```
const services = await Service
  .query()
  .with('categories')
  .orderBy('categories.id', 'desc')
  .fetch()
```

if don't work, use [innerJoin](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/query-builder#_joins)